# I can not get a disk bigger than 10G on google cloud trial. Is this the "unannounced" default?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I create a disk of size 300G when creating the instance, but when I create the instance I see it has reverted back to 10G. 
I just created an account to test the google cloud free trial with a view of transferring an AWS app over here, but I can't test it on 10G of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the free trials quotas. 
https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/free-trial-quotas

Recommendation from the doc, upgrade to paid account

> If you upgrade to a **paid account before the 60-day trial period ends, any remaining amount of your initial $300 credit remains in your account**. This credit expires after 60 days, when your free trial period would have originally ended.

So it is FOC if you upgrade to paid account until you used up the $300 credits .